# Connect Basler camera and show video on PyQt5 GUI

Tags: opencv, pyqt5, basler

I have an application like this [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jL1M.png) with one display to show real-time basler camera into it . I already figured out how to connect to Basler camera and show video on it but the video is not very smooth.

```
        #Connect to a camera
        for i in MainWindow.camera_db.all():
            if True:
                info = None
                for x in pylon.TlFactory.GetInstance().EnumerateDevices():
                    if x.GetSerialNumber() == i['id']:
                        info = x
                        break

                if info is not None:
                    camera = pylon.InstantCamera(pylon.TlFactory.GetInstance().CreateDevice(info))
                    camera.Open()
                    if MainWindow.viewer1 is None:
                        MainWindow.viewer1 = BaslerOpenCVViewer(camera)
                        logging.warning(f'Camera 1 - serial number: {i["id"]}-OK')
                else:
                    logging.warning('Camera with {} serial number not found'.format(i['id']))
```

and then I tried

```
    def update_frame(self):
        try:
            frame = MainWindow.viewer1.get_image()
            # frame = cv2.imread('test.jpg')

            self.load_display1(frame) # take a frame and show it on MainWindow.display
            return frame
        except Exception as e:
            logging.warning(str(e))

    self.time_get_image = QtCore.QTimer(self, interval=1)
    self.time_get_image.timeout.connect(self.get_image) #call update_frame function every 1ms to get a real-time video from Basler camera but it's not work well 
    self.time_get_image.start()
```

Is there another ways to connect to Basler camera continuous mode and show it on application.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code

---

```
    from pypylon import pylon
import cv2

# conecting to the first available camera
camera = pylon.InstantCamera(pylon.TlFactory.GetInstance().CreateFirstDevice())

# Grabing Continusely (video) with minimal delay
camera.StartGrabbing(pylon.GrabStrategy_LatestImageOnly) 
converter = pylon.ImageFormatConverter()

# converting to opencv bgr format
converter.OutputPixelFormat = pylon.PixelType_BGR8packed
converter.OutputBitAlignment = pylon.OutputBitAlignment_MsbAligned

while camera.IsGrabbing():
    grabResult = camera.RetrieveResult(5000, pylon.TimeoutHandling_ThrowException)

    if grabResult.GrabSucceeded():
        # Access the image data
        image = converter.Convert(grabResult)
        img = image.GetArray()
        cv2.namedWindow('title', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
        cv2.imshow('title', img)
        k = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if k == 27:
            break
    grabResult.Release()
    
# Releasing the resource    
camera.StopGrabbing()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

The code is taken from this github:[pypylon/samples/opencv.py](https://github.com/basler/pypylon/blob/master/samples/opencv.py)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer! Please, note, that the author of the question is asking about the ways to show the video stream in his QT window. Not in the window, created by OpenCV. Could you edit your answer accordingly, please?

Answer (score 0):

create a label and send the img to displayImage fucnbtion. you will get the image.

```html
from pypylon import pylon
import cv2

camera = pylon.InstantCamera(pylon.TlFactory.GetInstance().CreateFirstDevice())
camera.StartGrabbing(pylon.GrabStrategy_LatestImageOnly)
converter = pylon.ImageFormatConverter()
converter.OutputPixelFormat = pylon.PixelType_BGR8packed
converter.OutputBitAlignment = pylon.OutputBitAlignment_MsbAligned

while camera.IsGrabbing():
    grabResult = camera.RetrieveResult(5000, pylon.TimeoutHandling_ThrowException)
    # if grabResult.GrabSucceded():
    image = converter.Convert(grabResult)
    img = image.GetArray()

    self.displayImage(img)

    cv2.imshow("video", img)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    cv2.waitKey()

def displayImage(self, img):
    qformat = QImage.Format_Indexed8
    if len(img.shape) == 3:
        if (img.shape[2]) == 4:
            qformat = QImage.Format_RGB888
        else:
            qformat = QImage.Format_RGB888
    img = QImage(img, img.shape[1], img.shape[0], qformat)
    img = img.rgbSwapped()
    self.ui.Camera_lbl.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(img))
    self.ui.Camera_lbl.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
```